# Visual Studio 2013 debug toolbar buttons greyed-out (start-up project set)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Opened my C++ project with VS2013 today, weirdly the toolbar containing the debug start/pause, stop and restart buttons was missing. I added it back manually but was bewildered to discover all the buttons (start/pause, stop and reset) were greyed-out, not letting me press them. However, oddly if I press F5 the code will build fine.

I googled around but most solutions suggested setting the project to "set as startup project", which I already have. Another suggestion was the solution properties to be a "single startup project".

I created a new project and the same thing occurred, so it's not that my project is corrupt. I also tried repairing VS2013 to no avail and then I actually re-installed it, still the debug toolbar buttons were greyed out.

Anybody know what else I can do!? This was working fine all weekend.

UPDATE:

If I go to

Debug->Start Debugging

the buttons are visible/enabled whilst the program executes, but then upon clicking Stop they revert back to being greyed-out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2013 missing Start/Stop Debugging tool buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597645/visual-studio-2013-missing-start-stop-debugging-tool-buttons)

Comment: Did you try the Reset all settings described in several of the answers to the above link?