# How to run console application on command prompt window with visual studio Toolbar

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013 Console Application

[image: visual studio -2013 console application]

If I press F5 it works, but I want to press on the toolbar .
In the toolbar I have Page Inspector and more options, but I don't have console.
I do I add console option to the play button?

Comment: you need to add "Start" button to your toolbar, not "Page Inspector" which is a different button. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597645/visual-studio-2013-missing-start-stop-debugging-tool-buttons

Comment: I have tried "Reset all settings" and mark "debug" and "Standard", non of the solutions work for me..

Answer (score 1):

Its not a console application you have created but an ASP.NET project.
See the little globe icon i highlighted.
Changing the output type to console won't help.
Create a new one.

[image]