# Is there any shortcut to stop an infinite loop, every time I need to exit or close the VS Code application and reopen again?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

Many times I got encountered by infinite loop. I wanna say Is there any shortcut to stop infinite loop without closing compiler.

Comment: You mean without closing the IDE. The compiler (which is a command line program) runs as part of your task that is shown in the terminal. It's work is totally completed before you debug.

Comment: If you are encountering an infinite loop, then there is a problem with your input validation and a likely *matching-failure* and failure to empty `stdin` before the next iteration. Rather than worrying about how to close VS Code, why not worry about how to prevent the infinite loop?

Comment: Assuming this is the program you're developing that's locked up, I'd expect a stop button somewhere in the UI.

Comment: I think this SO Question worth a read : [Visual Studio 2013 missing Start/Stop Debugging tool buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597645/visual-studio-2013-missing-start-stop-debugging-tool-buttons) ; The shortcut is said to be S-F5 and it seems still relevant in VS2019 ... No trouble using Eclipse IDE ;o) (teasing ..)

Comment: No, it's well known that Eclipse doesn't have Visual Studio problems. It has Eclipse problems. Be nice if they all had the same problems. Easier to document. –

Answer (score 1):

You can press `ctrl-c` which sends `SIGINT` signal that immediately interrupts your program and stops it ( Unless you have a custom handler for this signal ;) )